# Which table contains customer support's email id in magento?

Tags: magento, email-address

I have to fetch sales representative's name and customer support's email id.

So in magento database which table contains this values?

I have tried my best.

but not able to find.

So can plz anyone help me?

we update/save this values from magento admin panel system/configuration/storeEmailaddresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Magento DB at hand, but I think it's in the table "core_config"; you can probably find it by "path" (which should be like "%storeEmailaddresses%"